# How Can I Modify Resource by Reflexil?

Tags: .net-assembly, embedded-resource, disassembly, reflector, reflexil

I want to change an image in a .net windows application without using source code.
How can I modify a image resource in a .net assembly by using Reflexil over Reflector?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is only Hex Editor. So you need to first save resource as file.Then find magic number of image.Delete everything before it & save it as image. You can now modify image & inject new image back to resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can save resource file by reflector, then use .NET Resourcer at here http://www.lutzroeder.com/dotnet/ to edit resource file, then use reflecxie replace resource file in Reflector